# Preventing leg injury when running

Tags: long-distance-running, injury-prevention

I'm trying to get back into running. The main reason I stopped last time was due to shin splints. I have been taking it much easier this time, reducing pace, time between runs, and distances. This has worked so far but I'm starting to feel pain in my shins again, is there a good way to prevent this? (Or at least reduce it) I have been wondering whether strapping them up, or getting a support would help.

Comment: Searching this site you'll find several q/a that address shin splints that may help: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1923/what-are-the-symptoms-of-shin-splints  and  http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13350/what-can-i-do-to-limit-shin-splints/13363#13363

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be any number of things causing pain and shin splints. Worn-out/improperly fitted shoes, bad running form, foot-strike, etc.

First, I would look into a proper shoe fit at a local and reputable running store.

Also, most stores in that category should have a treadmill and video equipment setup that will allow you to review your running form/strike.If your running form is the culprit, possibly causing you to landing too hard on your feet or just at a bad angle, doing core work can help improve. Maybe you're a heel-striker and a forefoot or midfoot strike would serve you better.

Take a look at this link http://www.active.com/running/articles/shin-splints-101-treatment-and-prevention-tips for a number of good articles.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you are able to find a resolution. Keep in mind that if you are already injured, trying anything new may not immediately help (or could possibly aggravate the injury more).

Something I forgot to mention is cross-train, cross-train, cross-train. Other cardio exercises like biking and swimming can be a huge help for running that are essentially non-impact.