# Pain in Front Part of Leg

Tags: running, strength, pain, jogging, walking

After running Just 5 minutes or so,(even while running very slowly) I get pain in lower frontal part of my leg. In fact, I get this pain even if I walk fast. It might be the bones or the muscles attached with the bones (I am not sure whether it's tibia or fibula). This pain gradually goes away if I rest half an hour or so!

Let me point out that I am not a regular "runner" and just started few weeks back. I run only during weekends but as I said earlier, the cause of pain does not seem to be running fast, as I get the pain even after walking fast.

Did anyone experience similar thing before? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [What Are The Symptoms of Shin Splints?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/1923/7706)

Comment: [Limiting Shin Splints](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13350/what-can-i-do-to-limit-shin-splints/) has good information. Since you are new to running you may want to look into your running surfaces, shoes, running form and exercise - dynamic warm-up, flexibility and strengthening.  Look at the link to "ankle dorsi-flexors" for a good strengthening exercise for your lower leg. Hip musculature strength is also important in preventing lower leg injuries and pain.

Comment: You may also want to see how you are landing - rearfoot or forefoot (anterior).  There is information on running techniques in this answer http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11858/stretches-and-muscle-work-for-supination-or-underpronation/11862#11862 quoting, "Overall, runners who reported utilizing a more anterior footstrike pattern reported fewer injuries than rearfoot striking runners".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds possible that you have shin splits http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shin_splints

They will go away with some time off.   This is common with individuals who are new to the level of training that are taking on.

My recommendation is to rest for 3 days and start again (rest means you don't have to stop training,  just don't do what you have been)

As you become better conditioned you won't have this problem anymore.  Stick with it,  you'll get there.